# Text input to file upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<textarea id="input_text" name="input_text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="decrypt" value="sm">
</form>
```

now I submit it, php is try to write $_POST['input_text'] to a file then do another action, after complete action, php 'll delete the file created.

```
<?php
$Path = dirname(__FILE__).'/temp/';
$File_NAME = time().'.txt';
$input_text = stripslashes($_POST['input_text']);
$fp=fopen($Path.$File_NAME,'w');
fwrite($fp,$input_text);
fclose($fp);
//do some curl action with the file, then delete the file
if(file_exists($Path.$File_NAME))
    unlink($Path.$File_NAME);
```

but if the text too strong, user submit the form, then they abort the page, so the file doesn't delete.
I want to direct change the $_POST['input_text'] to type='file', but user also can use it such as a textarea. so php don't need to delete the file because it is a tmp file.

Comment: what you exactly want and where is your code?

Comment: Please can you post your PHP code. From the sounds of it the file is being overwritten, are you using append to file?

Comment: too long in what sense? Something like a character limit ?

Comment: @KunalGupta because before delete file, php need to do curl action, if user not wait the curl complete, the file 'll not delete...

Comment: @HảiLê I updated my answer, is it solved?

Answer (score 1):

As per your Edit to the question, the possible solution is to first check the `$_POST['input_text']` for length before even opening the file. If the text is too long, show an error message.

I don't think that file is even required in that case.

**OLD ANSWER**:

Fetching the `$_POST['input_text]`, you can :

```
    $txt = $_POST['input_text'];
    $file = fopen("file.txt", "w+"); //w+ indicates read + write
    fwrite($file,$txt);              //to ride the 'input_txt'
```

Then perform the actions you want and finally delete the file if required using:

```
    fclose($file);
    delete("file.txt");
```

But make sure to grant the `PHP` page the permissions to Read/Write first.

Comment: oh no, I need to do some curl action with the "file.txt" before delete it,

Comment: Then perform the curl actions before deleting the file.